# Insert a column to differ medic treatment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with the dates of pacient treatment like this:

```
pacient_id |       date |    type | finish
         1 | 2021-01-05 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-01-10 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-01-22 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-01-30 | routine |    yes
         1 | 2021-02-04 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-02-12 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-02-19 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-02-22 | routine |    yes
```

I need a new column on a query that show if the consults are of first treatment or of second, example:

```
pacient_id |       date |    type | finish | treatment
         1 | 2021-01-05 | routine |   null |         1
         1 | 2021-01-10 | routine |   null |         1
         1 | 2021-01-22 | routine |   null |         1
         1 | 2021-01-30 | routine |    yes |         1
         1 | 2021-02-04 | routine |   null |         2
         1 | 2021-02-12 | routine |   null |         2
         1 | 2021-02-19 | routine |   null |         2
         1 | 2021-02-22 | routine |    yes |         2
```

When the finish column = yes, then the treatment is finish. The table have many pacients:

```
pacient_id |       date |    type | finish
         1 | 2021-01-05 | routine |   null
         2 | 2021-01-10 | routine |   null
         5 | 2021-01-22 | routine |   null
         2 | 2021-01-30 | routine |    yes
         1 | 2021-02-04 | routine |   null
         3 | 2021-02-12 | routine |   null
         9 | 2021-02-19 | routine |   null
         1 | 2021-02-22 | routine |    yes
```

So I order to pacient_id and date. Thanks for help.

Comment: In your second table, How do you know somebody is first  treatment or second treatment?

Comment: @Mark by the date.

Comment: your pacient_id  is all the 1, then I don't understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT pacient_id, date, type, finish
     , 1 + count(*) FILTER (WHERE finish = 'yes') OVER (PARTITION BY pacient_id ORDER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS treatment
  FROM your_table
```

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4d5f5004b1642f7a7cb4cb40d212542c)

Comment: ERROR:  RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED

Comment: I try `1 + count(*) FILTER (WHERE finish ilike 'yes') OVER (PARTITION BY pacient_id ORDER BY date) treatment,` this almost 100%

Comment: Sorry, you have to replace `RANGE` by `ROWS`. Answer updated accordingly with test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4d5f5004b1642f7a7cb4cb40d212542c)